# What are common spell materials that can't be replaced by a focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, druid, spell-components

I want to stock a roadside magic shop, whose owner has been murdered, with some stuff that might help my spellcasters, a druid and a wizard, cast up to level 4 spells.

I know that gems are pretty important, but they are already gone. So, what else can I put in there which they might benefit from later down the line?

Comment: What game (and edition, if applicable) are you playing? Lots of games use some sort of materials in their spellcasting systems, so we can't answer your question if we don't know what game you are playing.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Whops, sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this question is suitable for the site in its current form (even with a game system mentioned). As written, this seems more like an "idea generation" question, which we don't really handle. The space of potential answers is very large, and we don't really have any objective criteria with which to narrow down the types of components you're after. This question may be better suited for a traditional discussion forum, see here for our curated list: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think the title question is answerable (it's looking for costly spell material components that are used across multiple spells, from my reading), although yes, I think the question in the body is more idea-generation focused.

Comment: @ESCE Maybe so, I'll retract my close vote and give it a chance.

Comment: How far down the line? About what spell level?

Comment: @NautArch I'd say everything up to spell level 4.

Comment: One more question: Do you allow use of foci and component pouches?

Comment: @NautArch Yes. So everything that doesn't have a quantity to it wouldn't be of use to my players (if I understand the rules for these things correctly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from this [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ0PUubejT6BChmPqDHdAizsNkdfn6JsPGWC2BcaykJGzRzZc26TvOCGP_ua9R_6c3DvzIJpZa7yW49/pubhtml#) list. I found the link from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/n6bsor/full_list_of_costly_spell_components_sorted_by/) thread on Reddit.

**Druid**

| Spell Name | Component | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Snare | Rope, 25ft | 5gp (silk) or 5sp (hempen) |
| Summon Beast | Hollow gilded acorn | 200 gp |
| Summon Fey | Gilded flower | 300 gp |
| Land Circle | Incense and a sacrifical offering | 25 gp |
| Stoneskin | Diamond dust | 100 gp |
| Summon Elemental | Crystal vial + common components | 400 gp |

**Wizard**

| Spell Name | Component | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chromatic Orb | Single diamond | 50 gp |
| Find Familiar | Charcoal, incense, herbs | 10 gp |
| Identify | Pearl | 100 gp |
| Illusory Script | Lead-based ink | 10 gp |
| Protection from Evil and Good | Holy Water or Powdered Iron and Silver | (5cp-25gp)***(1gp suggested) |
| Snare | Rope, 25ft | 5gp (silk) or 5sp (hempen) |
| Arcane Lock | Gold dust | 25 gp |
| Continual Flame | Ruby | 50 gp |
| Magic Mouth | Jade dust | 10 gp |
| Clairvoyance | Glass eye (seeing) or jeweled horn (hearing) | 100 gp |
| Glyph of Warding | Powdered diamond | 200 gp |
| Magic Circle | Holy water or powdered silver and iron | 100 gp |
| Nondetection | Diamond dust | 25 gp |
| Summon Fey | Gilded flower | 300 gp |
| Summon Shadowspawn | Tears in a crystal vial | 300 gp |
| Summon Undead | Gilded skull | 300 gp |
| L's Secret Chest | Exquisite chest + replica | 5000gp + 50gp |
| Stoneskin | Diamond dust | 100 gp |
| Summon Aberration | Platinum inlaid vial w/ pickled tentacle and eyeball | 400 gp |
| Summon Construct | Ornate stone and metal lockbox | 400 gp |
| Summon Elemental | Crystal vial + common components | 400 gp |

The catch being, you'd need to know what spells your casters might be interested in. I'd suggest diamond dust as stoneskin is very useful. Holy water also pops up for a few spells.

Also, keep in mind that the players might just sell whatever you provide for them. Especially anything worth over 100 GP.

Comment: A Crystal Vial appears for a few spells as well, although those spells are a bit more niche (both being summoning spells).

Answer (score 1):

### Common Spell Components with gp value

Indirectly, any valuable spell component can help your wizard and druid cast spells, because it can be re-sold or traded for components they can use.

Components in common demand would need to be affordable by lower level, less affluent casters.  Let's say anything up to 100 gp. Common components listed here are for spells from the Players Handbook, as many of the spells from the various extension books appear more unusual and exotic, and their availablity in the game is optional. (You can ignore the pearl and diamond if these have been taken).

- **charcoal, incense, herbs** (10 gp) - find familiar
- **jade dust** (10gp) - magic mouth
- **lead-based ink** (10gp) - illusory script
- **gold dust** (25 gp) - arcane lock
- **marked sticks/bones** (25gp) - augury
- **holy water** (25gp/100gp) - protection from evil and good/magic circle; hurts undead
- **powdered silver and iron** (25gp/100gp) - protection from evil and good/magic circle
- **diamond dust** (25gp/100gp) - nondetection, stoneskin
- **ruby dust** (50gp) - continual flame
- **diamond** (50 gp) - chromatic orb
- **platinum rings** (50gp) - warding bond
- **glass eye, jeweled horn** (100gp) - clairvoyance/clairaudience
- **pearl** (100gp) - identify

*In addition, a substance that would be of high value for a wizard and should be available in any magic shop catering to them is the **magical ink** that wizards need for penning their spells, worth 50 gp per spell level.*

Aside from these, you also could have **spell books** (50 gp), other **books** (25 gp) on arcane subjects, **component pouches** (25 gp), and  **spell foci** (1 to 20 gp) on the shelves. You could consider useful alchemical substances, like **acid** (25 gp) or **alchemists fire** (50 gp), and tools of the trade like **parchement**(1 sp), **paper** (2sp), **scroll cases** (1gp), **ink** (10 gp), **vials** (1gp), **silk rope** (10 gp, for *rope trick*), and **robes** (1gp).

Lastly, although this is more costly and would be less common, you could consider a **crystal ball** (1,000 gp) as the high end item on display, because it is such an archetypical trapping for wizards.